# SQL Need min instance of time and total duration of a list of events that occur within 10 minutes of each other

Tags: sql

I have a table of ads and their aired datetimes. Sometimes the ads are aired one after another in groups of 2 or 3. I want to find the min air time when this happens to identify the start time of the group, as well as the sum of the ad durations for each group.

For example, in my table, I have these two groups of ads:

```
+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+ 
| sequence_id | ad_id              | ad_start_time      | ad_duration | 
+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+ 
| 28975352680 | M2783148-173883627 | 8/24/2020 19:12:50 | 20          | 
| 28976517640 | M2783148-174389250 | 8/24/2020 19:13:10 | 20          | 
| 28975352679 | M2783148-173883795 | 8/24/2020 19:13:30 | 22          | 
| 28976145221 | M2783148-173883627 | 8/24/2020 22:51:43 | 21          | 
| 28976517639 | M2783148-174389250 | 8/24/2020 22:52:04 | 20          | 
| 28976145219 | M2783148-173883795 | 8/24/2020 22:52:24 | 23          | 
+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

I want to update the table to get this:

```
+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+ 
| sequence_id | ad_id              | ad_start_time      | ad_duration | group_start_time   | group_duration | 
+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+ 
| 28975352680 | M2783148-173883627 | 8/24/2020 19:12:50 | 20          | 8/24/2020 19:12:50 | 62             | 
| 28976517640 | M2783148-174389250 | 8/24/2020 19:13:10 | 20          | 8/24/2020 19:12:50 | 62             | 
| 28975352679 | M2783148-173883795 | 8/24/2020 19:13:30 | 22          | 8/24/2020 19:12:50 | 62             | 
| 28976145221 | M2783148-173883627 | 8/24/2020 22:51:43 | 21          | 8/24/2020 22:51:43 | 64             | 
| 28976517639 | M2783148-174389250 | 8/24/2020 22:52:04 | 20          | 8/24/2020 22:51:43 | 64             | 
| 28976145219 | M2783148-173883795 | 8/24/2020 22:52:24 | 23          | 8/24/2020 22:51:43 | 64             | 
+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

Info on some of the other fields:

- sequence_id is a unique id in non-consecutive ascending order
- ad_id identifies the ad, but the ad can be present many times over the course of the day

Started with this query to try to identify the 1st/min instance and join back to the original table, but it's not very close to getting me what I need:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ad_id
        ,ad_start_time
        ,(
            SELECT TOP 1 ad_start_time
            FROM my_table AS tPrevious
            WHERE tPrevious.ad_id = t.ad_id
                AND tPrevious.ad_start_time < t.ad_start_time
            ORDER BY ad_start_time DESC
            ) AS previousCreated
    FROM my_table AS t
    ) AS joined
WHERE previousCreated IS NOT NULL
    AND DATEDIFF(min, ad_start_time, previousCreated) BETWEEN 0
        AND 10
```

The final query that worked was:

```
UPDATE my_table main
SET group_start_time = 
    (WITH cte
        AS (
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), ad_start_time) AS group_id
                ,MIN(ad_start_time) AS group_start_time
                ,SUM(ad_duration) AS group_duration
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), ad_start_time)
        ) 
        SELECT cte.group_start_time, cte.group_duration
        FROM cte
        WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), main.ad_start_time) = cte.group_id)
```

Comment: Having the second data table you provided; would you please provide an example of how you found the value of group_start_time and group_duration (formula)?

Comment: Hi! group_start_time = min(ad_start_time) of each group (so the first 3 records are a set of ads, they happen within a couple of minutes of each other, so they get 8/24/2020 19:12:50 - the date/time of the 1st record; and records 4 thru 6, which are another group, as they happen within a couple of minutes of each other, get  8/24/2020 22:51:43)   And group_duration = sum(ad_duration) of each ad in the group.

Comment: Hi Sena, I have posted a solution for your question, I did not find Group Id so I extracted Group Id from the Date of Ad. Please do not forget to Mark the Solution as OK if it satisfied your requirements, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Having that we do not have Group ID to use it while finding the aggregate values**, I assume that the *Date Part and Hour Part of the Time* is the *Group Id* so the solution is as following:

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), ad_start_time, 120) AS group_id
        ,MIN(ad_start_time) AS group_start_time
        ,SUM(ad_duration) AS group_duration
    FROM A_Sena_Temp_Table
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), ad_start_time, 120)
    )
UPDATE T
SET T.group_start_time = cte.group_start_time
    ,T.group_duration = cte.group_duration
FROM A_Sena_Temp_Table AS T
INNER JOIN cte ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), T.ad_start_time, 120) = cte.group_id
```

This is giving the following results to me (Please note that in my data the seq_id and ad_id are dummies)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  This did the trick!  I had to change the structure of the query as it did not accept that structure, but the pieces of the query were perfect.  The final query I ran is posted above.  Thanks again!

Comment: That is great news, I will be happy if you mark the answer as accepted :)